# Order string match results by max match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to search all match in a string and return all result ordered by max match results, let's say I have some strings:

```
var strArray = [
  "This is my number one string",
  "Another string that contains number",
  "Just for example string"
];

// Results of search "another number" should be:
var resultArrayOfIndexes = [1, 0];
```

So far I can search in a string but it returns all indexes where is at least one match, but I want the result array to be sorted by max count of matches.
My code:

```
function findMatch(list, phrase) {
  var preparedList = [],
    value = "";
  if (config.get("list").match.enabled) {
    for (var i = 0, length = list.length; i < length; i += 1) {

      value = config.get("getValue")(list[i]);
      var words = phrase.split(' ');
      var listMatchArr = [];
      $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
        var W = word.replace(/[\W_]+/g, ""); // match on alphaNum chars only
        if (match(value, W) && $.inArray(i, listMatchArr) == -1) { //phrase
          preparedList.push(list[i]);
          listMatchArr.push(i);
        };
      });

    }

  } else {
    preparedList = list;
  }

  return preparedList;
}
```

Comment: If one of the `strArray` elements has the word "number" twice, does that count as two matches?

Comment: Hah, good question! I think no, this is for products search purposes So only one match is sufficient. The problem is that the max unique matches to be first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a case-insensitive search is required.

The following code changes the phrase into an array of individual words, then maps the list to get back an array of objects in the form `{index: 0, matches:1}`, then filters out the ones where there were no matches, then sorts, then maps again to get just the indices.

```js
function findMatch(list, phrase) {
  var searchTerms = phrase.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
  return list.map(function(v, i) {
    v = v.toLowerCase();
    return {
      index: i,
      matches: searchTerms.reduce(function(a, c) {
        return a + (v.indexOf(c) !=-1 ? 1 : 0);
      }, 0)
    };
  })
  .filter(function(v) { return v.matches > 0; })
  .sort(function(a, b) { return b.matches - a.matches; })
  .map(function(v) { return v.index; });
}

var strArray = [
"This is my number one string", "Another string that contains number","Just for example string"
];

console.log(findMatch(strArray, "another number"));
```

Or expand the following for basically the same thing with ES6 features:

```js
function findMatch(list, phrase) {
  var searchTerms = phrase.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
  return list.map(function(v, i) {
    v = v.toLowerCase();
    return {
      index: i,
      matches: searchTerms.reduce((a, c) => a + (v.includes(c) ? 1 : 0), 0)
    };
  })
  .filter(v => v.matches > 0)
  .sort((a, b) => b.matches - a.matches)
  .map(v => v.index);
}

var strArray = [
"This is my number one string", "Another string that contains number","Just for example string"
];

console.log(findMatch(strArray, "another number"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match your phrase as well as count how many words are matches in your string if you are familiar with regex.
Assume that you want to know how many words were matched as well, you can store it as an array of objects where each object store the count number and the target string.

```
var strArray = [
    "This is my number one string", "Another string that contains number", "Just for example string"
];

function findMatch(list, phrase){
    var words = phrase.split(" ");

    var pattern = "";
    var length = words.length;
    // create pattern for regex match
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        pattern += words[i];
        if(i < length-1){
            pattern += "|";
        }
    }

    var counts = [];
    var re = new RegExp(pattern,"g");
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        var count = (list[i].toLowerCase().match(re) || []).length;
        //add to array if matched
        if(count > 0){
            counts.push({count:count,string:list[i]});
        }
    }
    //sort by max match 
    counts.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.count-a.count;
    });

    console.log(counts);
}

findMatch(strArray, "another number");
```

The result will look something like:

```
[ { count: 2, string: 'Another string that contains number' },
  { count: 1, string: 'This is my number one string' },
  { count: 0, string: 'Just for example string' } ]
```